# Wordpress - page names conflict physical directories

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is not a wordpress issue as all CMS seem to suffer the same problem running on Apache.

I have a page in wordpress: http://mysite.com/usa

I want to create a physical directory also /usa so that I can put subdirectories under it and put static html pages in there.

How can I tell the webserver using htaccess to not to default to the directory?

Thank you,

Jim

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you're using the WP-generated `.htaccess`, try adding the following `RewriteCondition` at the top, i.e. after the ones, which are already there

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/usa/
```

Another idea just sprang in mind and that would be just to move the blog in its own `/blog` sub directory and don't bother too much about WP's rewrite rules or if they would eventually mix up with your own ones for the rest of the site. If you'd choose to go that way, you'd need to change the `RewriteBase` in your WP's `.htaccess` from

```
RewriteBase /
```

to

```
RewriteBase /blog/
```

Comment: Hi @JimCubbageJr, sorry I've made a slight mistake but saw it and  just edited the `RewriteCond...` line.

Comment: Hello,

It is not working at the moment, let me try and explain in more detail.

I want to put all the states in the /usa directory
/usa/alaska.php
/usa/alabama.php
/usa/california.php

but I want it to work where the .php is removed that the end.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173706/htaccess-creating-directories-and-files-of-the-same-name - This is a more complete request, it will show you more what I am trying to do and why this won't work for me.