# htaccess - creating directories and files of the same name

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, directory, subdirectory

I want to create a bunch of files without an extension showing at the end.  The easiest way to do that was to do this:

```
/usa/index.php
/usa/alaska/index.php
/usa/alabama/index.php
/usa/california/index.php
```

What I want to do is this

```
/usa/alaska.php
/usa/alabama.php
/usa/california.php
```

and have it show up as:

```
/usa/alaska
/usa/alabama
/usa/california
```

However, I have one more level I want to add to this, the cities

```
/usa/alaska/adak.php
/usa/alaska/anchorage.php
/usa/california/los-angles.php
```

I don't want the ".php" showing up, but then each state exists as both a file and a directory.  What I want is an htaccess rule that serves up the file version of the file, not the directory which is the default.  I also want to strip the .php off of the end of the files so the final result looks like

```
/usa 
/usa/alaska (alaska.php)
/usa/alaska/adak  (adak.php)
```

I know I can get close to this by creating all the directories and using index.php for each directory, but then I will have thousands of directories each with one file in it and updating is a pain in the butt.  I would much rather have one directory with 1000 files in it, than 1000 directories with 1 file in it.

Please, can someone point me in the right direction and know that I am doing this for all 50 states.

Jim

Comment: Do you really need a separate `php` file for each state and each city in a state?

Answer (score 1):

I would also suggest using a single php (e.g. `index.php`) file and redirecting all urls starting with `usa` to it, instead of separating them in different directories and files. The you'd need a couple of rewrite rules like the following

```php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^usa/([^/.]+)$ index.php?state=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^usa/([^/]+)/([^/.]+)$ index.php?state=$1&city=$2 [L]
```

So then in your `index.php` you'd only need to check the `$_GET` parameters.

**Update:**
If you don't feel comfortable enough to use a database and pull the needed data from there you could always use the parameters to dynamically include/require the needed files. Something like this

```php
<?php
    $source = ''; //or the 'ROOT' directory
    if(isset($_GET['state'])) $source .= $_GET['state'].'/';
    if(isset($_GET['city'])) $source .= $_GET['city'].'.php';
    include($source);  // here $source would be something like 'alaska/adak.php'
                       // and is assumed that the dir 'alaska' is on the same 
                       // level as 'index.php'
?>
```

But to answer your **original question** nevertheless you could use the following `.htaccess`

```php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^usa/([^/.]+)$ usa/$1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^usa/([^/]+)/([^/.]+)$ usa/$1/$2.php [L]
```

Comment: Havelock, this would mean I would have to upload my database and dynamically create my pages on the fly.  I'm not sure I have the skill in PHP to do that.  It is easier for me to create a single php file with all the variables and store that on the computer.

Comment: @JimCubbageJr That would be one possibility. Another one would be to include(display) dynamically html/php files based on the `state` and `city` parameters.

Comment: @JimCubbageJr I updated my answer to exactly match your question now :)

Comment: Thank you, I had a similar idea last night, where it pulls the right file. Eventually, I could expand the file to dynamically pull from the database, but at that point I would want to include, in this case, CubeCart's database cache.  In effect, that is what I'm doing here, a poor man's cache.

Comment: Note: Answer to original question is incomplete.  I tried what you said, the problem is that if alaska.php and /alaska/ both exists, it will always server the directory to the browser, not the file.

Comment: after playing with this for a while, I believe your first suggestion is the best way to go as I can handle errors better.  Of course, I have to use PHP for regular expression matching.

Answer (score 0):

what about creating just one single file:

```
/usa/index.php
```

With

```
$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]
```

you can read the current URI.
Well, now if a user enters "http://domain.foo/usa/alaska" for example, he will get an 404 error of course.
But to call your `index.php` instead, you could write this line to the `.htaccess`:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /usa/index.php
```

Now the `index.php` receives everything what is written to the URI and you can match the result and include files or handle errors.

But maybe there is a better solution with .htaccess only, don't know. :)

Comment: I will have to check that solution, but I think the search engines will see the 404 in the header chain and invalidate every page below.

Comment: But even so, it does not get me beyond my current problem of trying to access /usa/alaska (alaska.php with extension removed) the file, vs having the web server show the directory of /usa/alaska/.